# how to add table borders for dynamic html in webview

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Here is my code

```
browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
browser.loadData("<html><body>"hml data"</body></html>","text/html`,encoding:"UTF-8");
```

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question.

Comment: loading html page to webview dynamically, it contains tables but borders are not applied for tables in the content

Comment: Where does your HTML data come from? If you generate it, you can just use `<table border="1">` as table tag.

Comment: data comes from database, it contains  tables also

Comment: Assuming you have a `String` variable named `html`, you can do `html = html.replace("<table", "<table border=\"1\"");` before you call `browser.loadData`.

Comment: it already contains border,but its not show in app

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of this issue?

Comment: thanks,it is solved by adding border to table tag  as you told.